# Reihenfolge von Verben im Nebensatz?

Tags: word-order, modal-verb

Was ist richtiger von den folgenden zwei Sätzen:

> Mir wurde mitgeteilt, dass ich es hätte abgeben sollen.

> Mir wurde mitgeteilt, dass ich es abgeben sollen hätte.

Mir ist klar, dass der erste Satz der richtige bzw. der meistbenutzte ist, aber ich hätte gerne gewusst, warum oder ob es eine Regel dafür gibt.

Meines Wissens nach landen die Verben bei Nebensätzen am Ende in umgekehrter Reihenfolge im Vergleich zum Hauptsatz. Wie z. B.: Weiß jemand, dass sie es gemacht hat?
Gibt es eine Art Regel: Wenn es drei Verben gibt, kommt dann das Hilfsverb als erstes?

Comment: "Was ist richtiger?" ist eine seltsame Frage. Gibt es denn richtiger als richtig? (abgesehen davon, dass sprachlich doch immer das richtig ist, was so verstanden wird, wie es gemeint war.)